# Optimizing PostgreSQL performance when using UUIDs as primary keys

Tags: postgresql, uuid, database-performance

I'm new to databases and have been considering using a UUID as the primary key in my project, but I read some things which made me interested to learn more about the performance.

Currently, I am using the `uuid` data type and the default value is set to `gen_random_uuid()`.

First of all, I was wondering: would UUIDs be less performant as a primary key?

If so...

- Are there any tips to optimize it, e.g. would it help if the PK was sequential, but another field contained a UUID, specifically for public exposure?
- Are there any similar alternatives which may be more performant?

(I'm not working with data of any considerable scale just yet; it's more of a theoretical question.)

Comment: Adding another column with another unique index would certainly make things slower, not faster. Btw: there is no such thing as `AUTOINCREMENT` in Postgres

Comment: Use a ulid instead

Comment: To expound on what @AsadAwadia said, using a ulid is better since they are sortable. Spec here: https://github.com/ulid/spec
random UUID's destroy performance because btree indices work best when the data can be sorted. ULID's are unfortunately not native, but you can find peoples' functions around.

Answer (score 8):

UUIDs are slower than keys generated by a sequence. You'll just have to accept that, there is no way around it. For that reason you use UUIDs only if you have a compelling reason, like the keys are generated outside the database or need to be unique across several database.

There is some deeper discussion of this [in my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/uuid-serial-or-identity-columns-for-postgresql-auto-generated-primary-keys/).

Answer (score 2):

While [this post](https://www.percona.com/blog/store-uuid-optimized-way/) focuses on MySQL, the solution offered could just as easily apply to any other database. It shows a significant performance boost by rearranging a UUID to have the time-related component be the first part of the value.